# create socket through proxy java

Tags: java, http, sockets, proxy

I have written the code which have to find the file size using http HEAD request through sockets... i try it in my home with non proxy connection its working ... but when i try it in my college with a proxy server whose ip is 172.16.4.6 and port 1117 it is not working......any suggestion......thanks.

```
public class Proxytesting {

    private static OutputStream os;
    private static InputStream in;
    private static BufferedReader reader;
    private static int Totalsize;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {         

            URL url_of_file=new URL("http://www.stockvault.net/data/s/124348.jpg");

            String hostaddress=url_of_file.getHost();

            ////////////////////for proxy server ///////////////////
            String textip="172.16.4.7";
            InetAddress host=InetAddress.getByName(textip);
            System.out.println(host);
            int port=1117;

            SocketAddress ad=new InetSocketAddress(host, 1117);
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, ad);

            Socket mysocket2 = new java.net.Socket();
            mysocket2.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostaddress,80));

            System.out.println("Socket opened to " + hostaddress + "\n");
            String file=url_of_file.getFile();
            System.out.println(" file = "+file);
            os = mysocket2.getOutputStream();

            String headRequest = "HEAD " +url_of_file+" HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                     + "Host: "+ hostaddress +"\r\n\r\n";
            os.write(headRequest.getBytes());

            in = mysocket2.getInputStream();
            reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String contlength="Content-Length:";

            // 1. Read the response header from server separately beforehand.
            String response;
            Totalsize = 0;
            do{ 
                response = reader.readLine();
                if(response.indexOf("Content-Length") > -1)
                {            
                    Totalsize = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(response.indexOf(' ')+1)); 
                    response = null;
                }
            }while(response != null);  

            System.out.println(" cont_lentht ##### == "+Totalsize);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Proxytesting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The error I get is:

```
Unknown host exception at for code [ mysocket2.connect(
    new InetSocketAddress(hostaddress,80));]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Do you get some kind of error message? An exception? Or does it just nothing?

Comment: it gives unknown host exception at for code   [ mysocket2.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostaddress,80));]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clues in comments. I found the solution to the problem.  There was a bug in the code I was constructing `InetSocketAddress` twice using a wrong port.  The complete working code is below.

```
public class Proxytesting {
    private static OutputStream os;
    private static InputStream in;
    private static BufferedReader reader;
    private static int Totalsize;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {         
            URL url_of_file=new URL("http://www.stockvault.net/data/s/124348.jpg");

            String hostaddress=url_of_file.getHost();
            ////////////////////for proxy server ///////////////////
            String textip="172.16.4.7";
            InetAddress host=InetAddress.getByName(textip);
            System.out.println(host);
            int port=1117;

            SocketAddress ad=new InetSocketAddress(host, 1117);
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, ad);

            Socket mysocket2 = new java.net.Socket();
            mysocket2.connect(ad);

            System.out.println("Socket opened to " + hostaddress + "\n");
            String file=url_of_file.getFile();
            System.out.println(" file = "+file);
            os = mysocket2.getOutputStream();

            String headRequest = "HEAD " +url_of_file+" HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                     + "Host: "+ hostaddress +"\r\n\r\n";
            os.write(headRequest.getBytes());

            in = mysocket2.getInputStream();
            reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String contlength="Content-Length:";

            // 1. Read the response header from server separately beforehand.
            String response;
            Totalsize = 0;
            do{ 
                response = reader.readLine();
                if(response.indexOf("Content-Length") > -1)
                {            
                    Totalsize = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(response.indexOf(' ')+1)); 
                    response = null;
                }
            }while(response != null);  

            System.out.println(" cont_lentht ##### == "+Totalsize);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Proxytesting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: In my case when i load the page for the first time, SOCKS server accept but does not connect..
i have seen from console..
Also it does not connects when i open another url in my webview..
Can you plz guide me in this regard ??

Answer (score 1):

You are making things very hard for yourself.  Use [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to connect through the proxy:

```
HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) url_of_file.openConnection(proxy);
conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
Totalsize = conn.getContentLength();
```

There are other HTTP clients which do a better job, but you should not create your own unless existing clients don't do what you need!

Comment: actually i want to create a socket connection to the remote server. and   using socket i want to find the file size.....

Comment: That's what my code does too.  In fact, it does pretty much the same as yours, except you get the proxy support for free. ;)

Comment: haammm!! yes mr David Grant you are quite right but i was looking for the basic level of coding for proxy server socket connection. and its goods for beginner to have the basic concepts.....